I can't include an .so file in my c++ project
I am trying to include libcurl in my large c++ project, which I am building on Ubuntu 24.04 using Visual Studio Code, CMake, and gcc.
I downloaded and built libcurl separately and have placed the libcurl folder, along with the built liburl.so (and so.4 and so.4.8.0 files) in my project dir/Engine/lib/curl.
I have added this to the gcc command:
-L/home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/ -llibcurl

But I get this error:
[build] /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -llibcurl

And just to sanity check my spelling, the output of ls on that dir:
ls /home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/libcurl*
/home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/libcurl.pc
/home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/libcurl.pc.in
/home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/libcurl.so
/home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/libcurl.so.4
/home/ian/dev/hedgey/Engine/lib/curl/libcurl.so.4.8.0

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT
Due to comments I am attempting to include libcurl using a more "cmakonic" method:
add_subdirectory( ${libDir}/curl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/curl)
target_link_libraries(${TORQUE_APP_NAME} curl)
addInclude(${libDir}/curl/src)

And I get the following error:
CMake Error at Tools/CMake/torque3d.cmake:606 (target_link_libraries):
Target "curl" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target.
One may link only to INTERFACE, OBJECT, STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to
executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.
EDIT
I have replaced the target_link_libraries with:
target_link_libraries(${TORQUE_APP_NAME} libcurl)
And I now get the rather inscrutable error:
[cmake] CMake Error:
[cmake]   Running
[cmake] 
[cmake]    '/usr/bin/ninja' '-C' '/home/ian/dev/hedgey/build' '-t' 'recompact'
[cmake] 
[cmake]   failed with:
[cmake] 
[cmake]    ninja: error: build.ninja:25157: multiple rules generate /home/ian/dev/hedgey/My Projects/hedge/game/resolve


The name of the library is only curl. The lib prefix is just a convention that marks the file as a library. This should be clearly shown in the documentation for the library. For almost any library actually.

By the way, when you use CMake you should not really add options directly to the command line (which the wording of your question make it sound like). Use the suitable target commands (like target_link_libraries). And if you build with the shared library, why not install it on your system and link with that? Why do you need to download and build your own library?

To clarify what @Someprogrammerdude said, -llibcurl should just be -lcurl. The linker adds the lib prefix automatically.

Ubuntu 24 has libcurl-dev. You don't need to build it from sources.

Well, I've a feeling I'm going to be told off for this, but I have edited the question (or added to it) to trying to use target_link_libraries.  And now the question is completely different.
But I would assume that curl was a library not an executable and should be able to be linked in like this.

Don't confuse target name and ld name. Now you should use libcurl target. BTW cmake is used improperly. Curl has libcurl.pc and cmake can use pkg_check_modules() and reduce manual directives.

Thanks.  I changed that and then got an error I can't parse (added to the question)

Maybe it should be something like
target_link_libraries(${TORQUE_APP_NAME} "${LIBCURL_LIBRARIES}")

Create another post with a [mre]

Side note : when you want to use 3rd party libraries also use a package manager (e.g.. conan)

I wouldn't be surprised if this question gets removed, but in case it doesn't (and with thanks to all the commentors), I fixed this.
I added this to the root CMakeLists.txt:
add_subdirectory(Engine/lib/curl)

And then this to my .cmake file:
target_link_libraries(${TORQUE_APP_NAME} CURL::libcurl)

